# Leftover Dough Made to Bread

Tags: bread

My question is this: Can you reuse the left over scone dough to make a loaf of bread? And how would you go about doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Scones are a very different type of product than yeast raised breads: scones rely on chemical leavening such as baking soda and/or baking powder for their rise, whereas regular breads are yeast leavened.

Converting one to the other would be far from trivial, even at the recipe level; trying to do so with dough already made is going to be counter-productive.

Instead, you can make more scones or quick breads, although these doughs don't tend to like extra manipulation or waiting around before being baked.  To extend the usefulness or variety of your products, you could make the basic mixture and then add the compliments like berries or chocolate chips to only part of the dough.

They should also freeze beautifully, and reheat quite well.

Answer (score 0):

The closest bread to scones would be the various [soda breads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soda_bread); the most common in my area being 'irish soda bread'.

The thing is, they're generally larger than scones, so I don't know about making it with the 'left over' bits ... maybe just the stuff that didn't fit on your making tray?

If so, look for soda bread recipes that call for bakin in a cast iron pan.  If you can only find ones that call for baking on a flat sheet, you might be able to use a pie plate.

If you only have a little bit left, I'd be inclined to add some extra liquid to them, and cook them stovetop as drop scones (what Americans call pancakes)